# Can I play the Campaign offline or at least without using the website?

Tags: battlefield-hardline

When I launch BFH from Origin it opens http://battlelog.battlefield.com/bfh which in turn (after some confusing navigation) launches the game on my PC.  Is there a way to bypass this and just launch the game directly?  Specifically the Campaign, which I would like to play offline, but if there's a way to launch multiplayer too that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, so for the Campaign mode this ends up being a lot simpler than I expected.  When Origin is in Offline mode, it will launch the game directly with no issues.  If you want to do it in Online mode (for access to friend chat or whatever), create a shortcut for or run:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Origin Games\BFH\bfh.exe" -webMode SP -Origin_NoAppFocus -requestState State_ResumeCampaign

(Your install location may vary.)

When launched from the website the game is passed some auth tokens in addition to the above.  I tried passing `-webmode MP` instead but the game just crashed, so I'm not sure if the website can be somehow bypassed for multiplayer or if the auth information will be required every time.

Comment: Unfortunately the pigstie that Origin/EA App is no longer allows offline mode.